# Loop through object items

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have pretty complicated object and I need to loop through multiple levels of items. This got tricky very fast and Im stuck now.

What I've tried *(Note that I added an error I get)*:

```
var stuffCount = Object.keys(stuff).length;

//Loop through initial items in object
for( i = 0; i < stuffCount; i++ ) {

    // Error occurs on this line:
    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'points' of undefined
    var pointCount = stuff[i].points.length; 

    var coordinates = [];

    //Loop through points in initial items
    for( r = 0; r < pointCount; r++ ) {

        coordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng( 
            stuff[i].points[r].lat, 
            stuff[i].points[r].lng ));
    }

}
```

---

**Object:** It's even more complicated but I made it as simple as possible for the sake of this question.

```
var stuff = {

    first: {

        center: {
            lat: 11,
            lng: 22
        },
        points: [
            {
                lat: 11,
                lng: 22
            },
            {
                lat: 33,
                lng: 44
            },
            {
                lat: 55,
                lng: 66
            },
        ]
    },

    second: {

        center: {
            lat: 11,
            lng: 22
        },
        points: [
            {
                lat: 11,
                lng: 22
            },
            {
                lat: 33,
                lng: 44
            },
            {
                lat: 55,
                lng: 66
            },
        ]
    },

    third: {

        center: {
            lat: 11,
            lng: 22
        },
        points: [
            {
                lat: 11,
                lng: 22
            },
            {
                lat: 33,
                lng: 44
            },
            {
                lat: 55,
                lng: 66
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

---

Im trying to make code smaller by using loops. It's used to show polygons on Google Maps. I could do it one by one but code is going to be pretty big because I have like 100 of them **+** I want it to be dynamic so that I can easily add new polygons in future without changing a lot of code.

**What's wrong with my code?**

Comment: there are numerous problems with it. Set a breakpoint and walk through it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is that you are trying to retrieve keys from your stuff object using a numbered index. You actually don't need the count of keys, use a `for...in` loop instead like so:

```
//Loop through initial items in object
for(var i in stuff) {

    // Error occurs on this line:
    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'points' of undefined
    var pointCount = stuff[i].points.length; 

    var coordinates = [];

    //Loop through points in initial items
    for( r = 0; r < pointCount; r++ ) {

        coordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng( 
            stuff[i].points[r].lat, 
            stuff[i].points[r].lng ));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused about the keys. You should be doing:

```
var stuffKeys = Object.keys(stuff);

//Loop through initial items in object
for( i = 0; i < stuffKeys.length; i++ ) {
    var pointCount = stuff[stuffKeys[i]].points.length; 

    var coordinates = [];

    //Loop through points in initial items
    for( r = 0; r < pointCount; r++ ) {

        coordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng( 
            stuff[stuffKeys[i]].points[r].lat, 
            stuff[stuffKeys[i]].points[r].lng ));
    }
}
```

What you have originally is asking for `stuff[0]`... which doesn't exist. You need `stuff[the first key in stuff]`...

Comment: more problems than that

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is get the points attribute out of 'first', so `stuff['first'].points`.

But instead, what you're doing is `stuff[0].points`, and 0 is not the key.

This is non-optimized, but should convey what you need to do:

```
stuff[Object.keys(stuff)[0]].points
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate through object properties. [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) can be used for iterating in array type property.

Answer (score 0):

**What's wrong with your code?** You are iterating through an object keys as if it were an array

`stuff['first']` is not the same as `stuff[0]`

How can you manage this? I would use [lodash](https://lodash.com/), to iterate like this:

```
_.each(stuff, function(item,name)
{
    _.each(item.points, function(point)
    {
        // do whatever
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `for in` loop to iterate through the object. See below example:

```
var stuffCount = Object.keys(stuff).length; //you don't need this

for (var obj in stuff) {

    var pointCount = stuff[obj].hasOwnProperty("points") ? stuff[obj].points.length : null;
    console.log(pointCount);

}
```